# How do I set up a image dataset in tensorflow for a CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a folder of images on my computer but I do not know how to set up the input layer. This is the code they provided on there sample page. I am not sure how to implement my folder into this format.

```
 def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: You should probably flatten the images into a single vector to feed in as input to the first layer.

Comment: You should have a look at input pipelines of tf.data ([link here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)). You basically create and preprocess a dataset object and an define iterator over it, which can be fed to a CNN. I would not recommend flattening the pictures as you lose the local neighbourhood relationships between pixels.

Comment: check similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666681/how-to-load-mnist-via-tensorflow-including-download/50669146#50669146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your images in the folders to vectors (set of numbers) to feed into the network.

In the above example of mnist you actually use a compressed binary version of the images. So no preprocessing is required from your end (except scaling pixels to be between 0-1).

Suppose you have a image that is RGB named `orig.jpg` in current working directory.

You will load that image as

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open('orig.jpg').convert('RGB')
img = np.array(img)
```

This will give you all the image content in the form of numbers to a numpy array variable. `img` in this case.

From your question, you are implementing a Convolution Neural network, so you do not need to flatten the `img` variable to one dimensional vector.

You can check the shape of the variable by running

```
np.shape(img)
```

Typically the shape will be a `(lenght, width, 3)`

One last step before you train your model with the image you may need to normalize the RGB values. You can do so by dividing `img` with 255. This usually improves your optimization algorithm

If you want to iterate over the complete image in a directory. You could do so by

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory_name):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):  
         # code to extract the values using os.path.join(directory_name,filename)
```

The complete code to iterate and save all the images with .jpg to np.array is as follows.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os.path

length = 128 # pixels in length
width = 128 # pixels in width


imgs = np.empty((0,length, width, 3)) #empty dummy array, we will append to this array all the images
for filename in os.listdir(directory_name):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(directory_name,filename)).convert('RGB')
        imgs = np.append(imgs, np.array(img).reshape((1, length, width, 3)), axis=0)
```

After the loop completes, the `imgs` will have a shape of `(num_image, length,  width, 3)`

Now you can use this `imgs` and build some input pipeline with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(....)` or you can directly use the `imgs`

Comment: Ok, but what about a folder with 400+ photos? This is very helpful

Comment: Okay I will update the answer for any number of images.

Comment: in the last section of the code it says: img = Image.open('orig.png').convert('RGBA') , what does 'orig.png' represent for the directory?

Comment: Sorry I will change

Comment: It says width not defined

Comment: Hardcode pixel length and width of image . Make sure all images have same length and width. If not crop

Comment: This code does not even work `imgs` and `np.array(img)` have different dimensions

Comment: Did I not mentioned that all images should of same dimension (128x128) say ? The append will fail if at least one differs. You can pad or crop images to make them all same dimension before loading

Comment: That's not the reason why it's not working. numpy won't add the two arrays together

Comment: Yes I got it. A reshape need to be called inside append. I will update the answer . Thanks

Comment: That's still wrong in needs to be reshaped with (1, length, width, 3)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the help