# Error: from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

My environment is as follows:

```
* Windows 7, 64 bit
* Anaconda Navigator 1.8.7
* python 3.6.5
* tensorflow 1.8.0
```

In python, I type:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

i got error as follows:

```
>>> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\input_data.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import data
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.error_ops import ignore_errors
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\error_ops.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import contrib_op_loader  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\contrib_op_loader.py", line 24, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("../../_dataset_ops.so"))
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\util\loader.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: E:\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\..\..\_dataset_ops.so not found
>>>
```

It also pops up a window saying:

```
The procedure entry point ?addcleanup@arenaimpl@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAAXPEAXP6AX0@Z@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library _pywarp_tensorflow_internal.pyd
```

Please help. thank you very much in advance.

Warmest Regards,
Suryadi

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666681/how-to-load-mnist-via-tensorflow-including-download/50669146#50669146

Comment: I run code at your link, got error: ---> 16    train_image.shape = (10, 784)
NameError: name 'train_image' is not defined

Comment: There is no `train_image` refined as part of the code, its a comment. Make sure you copy the code correctly, i just tried it and its working fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist` and `tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset('mnist')` are throwing deprecated warnings. You can load through `keras datasets` :

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data().
```

You can check on how to load the mnist and use it for training here: [How to load MNIST via TensorFlow (including download)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666681/how-to-load-mnist-via-tensorflow-including-download/50669146#50669146]).

Answer (score 1):

You should also convert the image data to a floating point representation.

```
 mnist_train, mnist_test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
 train_data = np.float16(mnist_train[0])  # Returns np.array
 train_labels = np.asarray(mnist_train[1], dtype=np.int32)
 eval_data = np.float16(mnist_test[0])  # Returns np.array
 eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist_test[1], dtype=np.int32)
```